# Markdown Lorem Ipsum generator?

Tags: html, markdown, lorem-ipsum

There are dozens of html/text Lorem ipsum generators around; However something I haven't found which I find strange with the prevalence of Markdown online is a Markdown Lorem Ipsum generator.

Does anyone know of one online somewhere or of any reason one wouldn't exist?

Comment: Markdown Lorem Ipsum ? Can you give example ?

Comment: Strange indeed, since that's one of the easiest things you can build. If there really isn't one I think I'll build one later today :)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Something like http://loripsum.net/ but would generate the output as markdown instead of html; also would be useful if it included images in the ipsum using something like placehold.it images.

Answer (score 18):

I recently came across this awesome markdown lorem ipsum generator called [**Lorem Markdownum**](http://jaspervdj.be/lorem-markdownum/).

It's configurable and includes random generation of all markdown elements using Markov chains and other cool stuff.

Here's a sample output:

---

## Amoris Pindusque spreta Denique et positus quoniam

### Inquit Tyriis cervos circuit Hyrie ocius sitientes

Renuente feruntur fontibus pares, ait tertia lacunabant animo, est. Limina
pulvere victima fores Aeacidae. Cum sua muneris [spargit albis
glomerabat](http://www.thesecretofinvisibility.com/) novercae puniceo. Vel quae
hac valuisse et artus intexuit ramosam Herculeos umbras. Ferarum niger.

- Vestigia votorum turbatusque putes haeremusque matrem fateor
- Iam natam sic fataliter uterque exiliis una
- Proceres aethera

### Amando littera solantia iam Paridis priorem dixisse

Illis altior bracchia lapides decus *increpat* ignota. Lucis suis eheu nec, sive
dicta villosa deos flexi me parvo tendere, talibus semper Polydegmona ait.
Refert versato vultus, percussit pavor, primum matrem care grande, *iam adeundi*
est **arenti**! Dracones hinnitus soleo sequenti, Arethusae me morte sanguine;
inscripsere summa: ego.

```
logicPim = imapOptical(19 - laserIconSpreadsheet, text_technology(
        yobibyte_regular_hyperlink, icio_gbps_compiler),
        swipeOdbcInterface.gnutella_copyright(backside_netmask,
        abend_camelcase, mbrCycleTag) + smmFileMemory);
waveform_server(mini_degauss_paper(ccMegapixel + default_minisite_ieee,
        script_system));
rtf_restore_crossplatform(barBlu, css);
```

Quod res fulmen in, hunc, atque vivum. Quid aequor captivo illum, clausit in
dubitas mixta. Est penates est [celas](http://seenly.com/), modo perque reticere
orbem timore neptis refero. Sperneret viridis iaculis avis Phrygiisque alto!

Answer (score 5):

I did this little thing while learning emberjs. Hope it helps!

http://juanda.me/tests/ember-lipsum-md/

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score -2):

This http://www.lorem-ipsum-html.com/ it is simple and clean, This provides code snippets with html like this:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
- Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
- Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.